# Is SP initiated requests without AuthnRequest an industry standard?

Tags: saml, opensaml

I am working on SAML2.0. One of our clients(IDP) requested us (SP) to have SP initiated requests without sending AuthnRequest.

Instead of sending AuthenRequest they have asked us(SP) to send a parameter on the URL that can tell them that the request has come from the designated SP. Is it an industry standard to implement SP initiated requests without having AuthnRequest parameter?

Comment: not a question at all ... a joke probably

Answer (score 2):

I would actually call this IDP initiated, as from the viewpoint of SAML, the IDP sends the first message. IDP initiated is part of the standard, so it does not break SAML.

But if you are going to have the SP tell the IDP to start authentication I would consider it bad practise not to have the SP start this by using a SAML AuthnRequest.

This would be a more interoperable approach making it easier to use standard SAML product without the need for customizations.

Answer (score 1):

No it's not. However, from our experience, some IdPs do not support SP-initiated SSO. Instead, they require a redirect to the IdP including a parameter that identifies the SP. This then will trigger IdP-initiated SSO to the SP. This is not covered by the SAML v2.0 specification and therefore the format of the URL including the parameter name etc is not standardized.

I suggest double checking with the IdP to see whether they do support SP-initiated SSO as per the SAML specification. Perhaps they simply haven't enabled this support. If they don't then you're only option is to use this non-standardized approach.